# Maven Compile cannot find jars from rt.jar

Tags: java, maven, tools.jar, rt.jar

i have the following dependency in my app as I need some classes from rt.jar.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0_06</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I actually did `mvn clean compile -X` to print all debug info. It looks like it can identify the location on `-classpath` but always complains the the package doesn't exist during build failure.

Is there something I need to configure specifically to add this thing as part of my build?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Slaw             jdk1.8u162. I know that they are not quite "Available" from java9 onwards. I am simply adding them as part of my JDK that's why it's "system" scope.

Comment: Is this Oracle JDK

Comment: @Isuru           yes Oracle JDK

Comment: There is a reason why that are not available anymore...So you are adding com.sun artifacts to JDK 1.8 build? sounds really wrong..and system scope anyway...can you elaborate why the rt.jar is needed? I would suggest to migrate the code...

Comment: @khmarbaise     we have some old and experimental features that use rt.jar and I cannot disclose certain details...but the question isn't about migration, it's about dependency resolution, and why it cannot find the jars. And it's available as part of JDK 8 which I am using.

Comment: you don't need to add this dependency. it should pick those classes from java class path. I just checked using class file from rt jar. It compiles without this dependency